# with and arguments scope length property

Tags: javascript

```
with (function(x, undefined){}) length;
```

Result of the above statement is 2 (console.log(length), what is the explanation ? It's giving the length of *arguments* why that ?

And why

```
function f(a,b,c,d) {
    console.log(length);
}

f();
```

is 0 ? isn't it the same thing ?

Comment: [Function.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length)

Comment: got it, valid answer in my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example is giving the number of arguments in the **declaration**, which is the definition of [`Function.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length).

Note that this is **not** the length of `arguments`, which does not exist except **inside** the function when it is **called**.

Your second case is printing the value of [`window.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/length..), which is the number of frames in the window.